# Hide ComboBoxItem picker in smartGWT

Tags: combobox, smartgwt

I am working with smartGWT. We have the ability to explicitly show the picker in the ComboboxItem using the method showPicker().
Do we have something which will hide the picker?

Comment: try redraw() on the item